# Delayed awarding of beta badges?

Tags: support

So we went public a few hours ago and I noticed that most of the other people who I remember interacting with in private beta have their shiny new beta badges but I don't see one on my profile. I've got 13 votes, 5 answers (minimum score of 2), and I've visited the site on 12 days (including the last 8). Am I missing something here? Is it possible that there's some sort of delay?

Comment: We all voted, and decided you get no badges.

Comment: @TrevorArchibald - that's polar vortex cold...  :-)

Comment: @GlenH7 Polar vortex was last year, this year I'm bombogenesis cold.

Comment: [Relevant chat transcript](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19865142#19865142)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a little digging for you and confirmed that you did meet the requirements for days visited and posts with score > 0. However, your votes are not visible even to site moderators, so I can't confirm that you met the voting requirement.

I see on your profile that of your 13 votes, 7 were cast in the month of February. Of those 7 votes in February, at least 4 would have to have been cast prior to 2015-02-02 18:32:59 to qualify you for the Beta badge. What I'd like for you to do is look through [your own voting history](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/users/131/?tab=votes) and check the timestamps to see how many of your votes were actually cast prior to that date and time.

Remember that the time zones must agree. In most cases on Stack Exchange, hovering your mouse cursor over a time or date in your browser window will display the full UTC time stamp as hover text. If you [hover over the "N days ago" text on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60453/engineering) you can see the UTC time stamp for the end of private beta. The letter "Z" at the end of the time stamp indicates it is given in UTC time ([the "Z" stands for "Zulu time"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time#Time_zones)).

If you can confirm that you met the voting requirement, then this may be due to a bug.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the times are good... FWIW. Not that big a deal, I suppose. It would have been nice to get the medal since I spent a LOT of time on this site in private beta but I suppose that's the way the medal crumbles. ;)